# scipy.optimize.minimize is consuming high-RAM runtime

Tags: python, deep-learning, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

Scipy.optimize.minimize is consuming lot of RAM and the session is crashing. I am executing the code in google colab where 12.69 GB of RAM is provided. I am using MNIST datatset which also not very huge. My constraint and objective function is given as -

```
#Declaring the minimization equation here

def objective(x):
    alpha = x[0]
    v=x[1:len(x)]
    vnorm=torch.linalg.vector_norm(v) * torch.linalg.vector_norm(v)
    return alpha+(vnorm/2)

#Declaring the constraint here

def constraint(x):
    alpha=x[0]
    v=x[1:len(x)]
    return -(A @ v)+alpha


cons={'type':'ineq','fun':constraint}
result=minimize(objective,val,constraints=cons,options={"disp":True})
```

Here size of A is 88 bytes and is a 2 by 318737 tensor. The val in the minimization equation is 318738 by 1 tensor

val has been copied to cpu by val.cpu().numpy() so that it works with scipy. However the execution is failing once the minimize() method is called because the RAM is getting over loaded and it is exceeding 12.69 GB RAM offered by google colab. How can I reduce this? Is there any workaround to this? or any other optimizer which I can use?